# Proper way to use MySQL GROUP BY for returning one result from a referenced table

Tags: mysql, group-by

I often have a situation with two tables in MySQL where I need one record for each foreign key. For example:

```
table post {id, ...}
table comment {id, post_id, ...}

SELECT * FROM comment GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY id ASC
-- Oldest comment for each post
```

or

```
table client {id, ...}
table payment {id, client_id, ...}

SELECT * FROM payment GROUP BY client_id ORDER BY id DESC
-- Most recent payment from each client
```

These queries often fail because the "SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause" and contains nonaggregated columns.

### Failed Solutions

1. I can usually work around this with a `min()/max()` but that creates a very *slow* query with mis-matched results (`row with min(id) isn't equal to row with min(textfield)`)

   ```
   SELECT min(id), min(textfield), ... FROM table GROUP BY fk_id
   ```
2. Adding all the columns to `GROUP BY` results in duplicate records (from the `fk_id`) which defeats the purpose of `GROUP BY`.

   ```
   SELECT id, textfield, ... FROM table GROUP BY fk_id, id, textfield
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as @GurV but using a join instead of a correlated subquery.  The basic idea here is that the subquery finds, for each post which has comments, the oldest post and its corresponding `id` in the `comments` table.  We then join back to `comments` again to restrict to the records we want.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM comments t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT post_id, MIN(id) AS min_id
    FROM comments
    GROUP BY post_id
) t2
    ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id AND
       t1.id      = t2.min_id
```

Comment: Takes about 700ms on a test 500k InnoDB table. Explain shows it's digging through 20k records even with a `LIMIT 200` so perhaps someone can recommend the correct index(es).

Comment: I"m not sure that an index would be beneficial here.  700ms for half a million records seems pretty fast to me given the nature of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated query with aggregation to find out the earliest comment for each post:

```
select *
from comments c1
where id = (
        select min(id)
        from comments c2
        where c1.post_id = c2.post_id
        )
```

Compound index - `comments(id, post_id)` should be helpful.

If you are querying the whole table with many rows, then it *will*. This query is more useful and performant if you are querying for a small subset of posts. If you are querying the whole table, then @Tim's answer is better suited I think.

Comment: What indexes are needed? I tested this on a small InnoDB table of 500k records with `id = PRIMARY KEY`, and `post_id = FK` and it took 16 seconds!

Comment: @Xeoncross - Update my answer with some info.